# pyinstaller can't make correct exe file with gspread. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gspread'

Tags: python, pyinstaller, gspread

**Pyinstaller doesn't see gspread.**

```
import cv2 as cv
from time import time
import numpy as np
import dxcam
import gspread
import datetime
import wmi
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

*All another lib of my project pyinstaller finding correctly.*

```
pyinstaller myProj.py
```

*When i run the .exe i get: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gspread'*

I tried copy all modules including gspread to the "dist\myProj" folder, after run the myProj.exe, i get this:

```
> C:\myProj\dist\myProj>myProj.exe Traceback (most recent call last):
> File " myProj.py", line 5, in <module> File
> "C:\myProj\dist\myProj\gspread\__init__.py", line 16, in <module> from
> .auth import oauth, service_account, service_account_from_dict File
> "C:\myProj\\dist\myProj\gspread\auth.py", line 16, in <module> from
> google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow File
> "C:\myProj\\dist\myProj\google_auth_oauthlib\__init__.py", line 21, in
> <module> from .interactive import get_user_credentials File
> "C:\myProj\\dist\myProj\google_auth_oauthlib\interactive.py", line 27,
> in <module> import google_auth_oauthlib.flow File
> "C:\myProj\\dist\myProj\google_auth_oauthlib\flow.py", line 63, in
> <module> import wsgiref.simple_server ModuleNotFoundError: No module
> named 'wsgiref' [2732] Failed to execute script 'myProj' due to
> unhandled exception!
```

*What can i do to fix this?*

Comment: Did you check [Helping PyInstaller Find Modules](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#helping-pyinstaller-find-modules)? Try listing it as hidden import when convert to exe.

Answer (score 0):

first install package **'gspread'** with your terminal like that :

> pip install gspread

then make another exe file with this command :

> pyinstaller --onefile yourPythonFilename.py

then in your project library go to dist folder
and the **yourPythonFilename.exe** file is the file you created.

Comment: doesn't work. I get same Error:
C:\myProj\dist>myProj
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myProj.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gspread'
[704] Failed to execute script 'myProj.py' due to unhandled exception!

Comment: @kokinas what do you see when you run pip install gspread in your terminal ?

Comment: 15 lines Requirement already satisfied,
5 lines WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -pencv-python (c:\users\kokinas\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)